# PowerShell script for creating sub directories inside the blob containers and insert some data into it

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a multiple Azure Storage Accounts. I want to create the folder structure inside the Azure Storage blob containers and insert some data into it using PowerShell.

So, can anyone suggest me how to write the PowerShell script for creating sub directories inside the blob containers and insert some data into it.

Comment: Hi, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask (in particular how you've attempted to solve the problem yourself). I didn't vote down, but I suspect it will be the feedback of those who did.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Azure storage blob containers does not really support creating folders, folders are created as part of the path when uploading the file to the container, so there is no separate action that only creates empty folder. For example:

```
folder1/image.png
folderA/folderB/image2.png
```

And the SDK has API that supports getting the files based on "folder" path.

Powershell example of "creating" folder1 is:

```
Connect-AzureRmAccount

$storageAccount = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName 'myresourcegroup' `
-Name 'storageaccount' 

Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File C:\tmp\0001.png `
-Container files `
-Blob 'folder1/0001.png' `
-Context $storageAccount.Context
```

This will respectively "create" folder1 and upload 0001.png to that folder

Comment: Can you please update your answer with multiple storage accounts.

Comment: Well in the second command you get specific storage account, and in third you upload file to it, so basically you can repeat commands two and three for each storage account you get. I'm not really sure what multiple accounts mean? is it the same folder/file structure on all of these?

Comment: No, different folders and files in each storage account blob.

Comment: Well, I believe then that I answered your question

Comment: Is it possible to upload multiple files at time.

Comment: you can do something like this
https://www.nhaustralia.com.au/blogcontent/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/powershell-azure-container-7.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187055/discussion-between-stanke-and-pradeep).